# TableViewCell color not changing on tapping

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When I am tapping on my table view cell, its background color is not changing to blue. Any reason for this?

On tapping of a cell, I am putting a check mark on right view of the cell and if I tap on same cell which has the checkmark, cell glows with blue background color but not on the cell which do not contain the checkmark.

I tried

```
[iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath].selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

in my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
```

but it is not helping.

Comment: I’ve noticed you’ve been using the cocoa tag extensively for iOS-related questions. Just so you know, the corresponding iOS tag is cocoa-touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the cell's `selectionStyle` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Cell setup

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue; // or Gray/None

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also do this by this way

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];

    }
```

You can change the color of textlabel,cell,cell's content view.
Hope this would also help you.